# Which region took the majority of wealth?

Tags: money, maseches-kiddushin, avot-derabbi-natan

Avos d’Rebbi Nassan 28:1:

> רבי נתן אומר [...] ואין לך חכמה כחכמה של ארץ ישראל. ואין לך יופי כיופי של ירושלים. ואין לך עושר כעושר של מדי. ואין לך גבורה כגבורה של פרס. ואין לך זנות כזנות של ערביים. ואין לך גסות כגסות של עילם. ואין לך חנופה כחנופה של בבל שנאמר ויאמר אלי לבנות לה בית בארץ שנאר. ואין לך כשפים ככשפים של מצרים:
>
> R’ Nassan says: [...] There is no wisdom like the wisdom of Eretz Yisrael. There is no beauty like the beauty of Yerushalayim. There is no wealth like the wealth of Media. There is no strength like the strength of Persia. There is no harlotry like the harlotry of Arabs. There is no arrogance like the arrogance of Eilam. [...] There is no witchcraft like the witchcraft of Egypt.

Contrast to Kiddushin 49b:

> עשרה קבים חכמה ירדו לעולם תשעה נטלה ארץ ישראל ואחד כל העולם כולו עשרה קבים יופי ירדו לעולם תשעה נטלה ירושלים ואחד כל העולם כולו עשרה קבים עשירות ירדו לעולם תשעה נטלו רומיים קדמונים ואחד כל העולם כולו [...] עשרה קבים גסות ירדו לעולם תשעה נטלה עילם ואחד כל העולם כולו [...] עשרה קבים גבורה ירדו לעולם תשעה נטלו פרסיים וכו' [...] עשרה קבים כשפים ירדו לעולם תשעה נטלה מצרים כו' [...] י' קבים זנות ירדו לעולם תשעה נטלה ערביא כו' [...]
>
> Ten portions of wisdom came to the world; nine were taken by Eretz Yisrael, and one by the rest of the world. Ten portions of beauty came to the world; nine were taken by Yerushalayim, and one by the rest of the world. Ten portions of wealth came to the world; nine were taken by Old Rome, and one by the rest of the world. [...] Ten portions of arrogance came to the world; nine were taken by Eilam, and one by the rest of the world. [...] Ten portions of strength came to the world; nine were taken by Persia, etc. [...] Ten portions of witchcraft came to the world; nine were taken by Egypt, etc. [...] Ten portions of harlotry came to the world; nine were taken by Arabia, etc. [...]

(In the bracketed ellipses in both quotes they discuss attributes that don’t appear on the other list.)

Almost all of these attributes are identical across both lists: anything which Avos d’Rebbi Nassan says there’s nothing like it, Kiddushin says nine portions of that trait went there.

There’s one exception, though: wealth. According to Avos d’Rebbi Nassan, wealth went to Media, while according to the Gemara, wealth went to Old Rome. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: One of the texts was written under the Roman empire and one under the Persian empire?

Comment: Please check that my edit reflects your intent and revert otherwise.

Comment: Are you seriously trying to read it literally and set it as Halacha forever?

Comment: @AlBerko Reading it literally != set it as Halacha forever. I see two sources that perfectly match each other except for one line, and I seek to understand the difference. However you understand it, literally, metaphorically, whatever, the difference needs to be explained.

Comment: Doesn't the main Talmud trump the Massechtot Ketanot (Minor Tractates, of which Natan is one) -- which is why they are "ketanot" (minor).

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi (AdR”N is not a Masechta Ketanah, but it is Braisa.) It’s only Mishnah that trumps Braisa; Gemara doesn’t trump Braisa. Even if it does, it still doesn’t explain why the sources differ.

Comment: @DonielF -- I always thought Natan was a minor tractate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_tractate

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I’ll trust Tosfos over Wikipedia any day. On BK 25b they refer to it as Tosefta Avos. It’s certainly printed with the Masechtos Ketanos, but it isn’t one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=17513#p345254) in the forum of Otzar Hachochmah, the Media version is the result of censorship and it should actually be Rome. And indeed, you can see the original version in [the first printed edition](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58139&pgnum=15):

[image]